# Compare two file with same content in the best way

Tags: regex, perl

I want to compare two file which contain the same thing. Below is my code to compare two file but no working properly and i dont know what the error is

```
    open ( FILE , '<', "data.txt" ) or die $!;
    open ( FILE1 , '<', "data1.txt" ) or die $!;
    my @data = <FILE>;
    my @data1 = <FILE1>;
    my $match = 0;
    my $no_match = 0;
    for ( $i =0 ; $i<=864 ; $i++ ) {
        my $data_line = $data[$i];
        my $data1_line = $data1[$i];
        if ( $data1_line eq $data_line ){
            $match += 1;
            print " total match = $match \n";
        } 
        else {
            $no_match +=1 ;
            print " line $i no match\n ";
        }
    }
```

For example my file data.txt contain something like this

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
....
```

and my data1.txt contain thins like this

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 22 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
....
```

I also try to split by space and compare but it make my code longer. What way is the best way to compare two file? My expected output is it will show me which line not match and how much is the total matching line.For above example i would like to show the results as below

```
  "line 2 not match and total match line =1".
```

However the output i get from above script is all line not matching. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think longer code is bad? There is usually no _best way_. What output do you get? What is the exact input for both data.txt and data1.txt? Please [edit] your question and include that, as well as the expected output.

Comment: Do you need corresponding lines to match literally or semantically (e.g. numbers in the lines should match and delimiters don't matter)?

Comment: Hi @simbabque, i edited my question , i am not quite understand your mean for exact input. Thanks

Comment: Hi @DmitryEgorov, yes i just wan to match the number. Thanks

Comment: @tim: so the lines "1_2" (one space between 1 and 2) and "1___2" (three spaces between 1 and 2) should be considered matching, shouldn't they?

Comment: Hi @DmitryEgorov, actually the two file will have exact same delimiters just the number will be different, so in this case i no care about the delimiters in my code. Thanks

Comment: Just show us an example for both files that you want to match.

Comment: @simbabque, i edit my question above with example. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your `data1.txt` has `22` where `data.txt` has `21`, so the files are different and the result is correct.

Comment: @Borodin the result i want to show is not match for the line 2

Comment: You say it prints `total match line =1` and `line 2 not match` which is correct.

Comment: Hi @Borodin, thanks to point out this, i edited my question as previous is unclear the output show above is what i want but my result is even first line also not match. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 !/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;

    # read the data
    my ($file1, $file2) = ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt');
    my @firstfile;
    my @secondfile;

    open (my $fh, '<', $file1) or die "Cant open $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh>) {
       chomp $line;
       push @firstfile, split / /, $line;
    }

    open (my $fh2, '<', $file1) or die "Cant open $!";
    while (my $line = <$fh2>) {
       chomp $line;
       push @secondfile, split / /, $line;;
    }
    # cmp the data in files
    my %cmp;
    %cmp = map {$_ => 1} @firstfile;

    foreach my $element (@secondfile) {
        if ($cmp{$element}) {
          print "$element exists in both files\n";
        } else {
          print "$element  only in second file\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick shell solution to check if the two files have the exact same content. If the outcome of the following script is zero the two files have the same content.

```
diff data.txt data1.txt | wc -l
```

More specifically:

```
diffLines=$( diff data.txt data1.txt | wc -l )
if [ $diffLines -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Files have the same content"
fi
```

Comment: That's silly.  The `cmp` command does this much more efficiently and idiomatically.

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: It's not more efficient? Or it doesn't compare files and report whether they are identical?

Comment: I'd use `diff`'s return code (0=same, 1=different) and write this as `if diff -q data.txt data1.txt >/dev/null; then echo "same"; fi`. No need to make `diff` print _all_ the differences.